# Adding arrays to a php variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am using PDO in order to select some values from my database. 
 
For each iteration of my $teachArray, I store the selected array into my $language_id variable. 
I then get rid of any empty array that I have inside my $language_id and assigning it to my $NoEmptyArray_language_id
 However, I am only storing the last array inside of $language_id in $NoEmptyArray_language_id.

I would like to concatenate every array in $language_id into $NoEmptyArray_language_id.

I cannot use `$NoEmptyArray_language_id .= $language_id;` since it will give me an error: Array to String conversion

Here is my simple query.

```
$sqlFindId = "SELECT language_id
              FROM language_skill
              WHERE person_id = :person_id AND language_learning = :language_learning AND language_id = :language_id";

             $NoEmptyArray_language_id = "";
                foreach ($teachArray as $dataTeach)
                {
                    $query = $handler->prepare($sqlFindUser);
                    $query->bindValue(':person_id', $_SESSION['person_id']);
                    $query->bindValue(':language_learning', 1);
                    $query->bindValue(':language_id', $dataTeach);
                    $query->execute();
                    $language_id = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
                    if ( count( $language_id ) != 0 ) {
                        $NoEmptyArray_language_id .= $language_id;

                    }

                }
                print_r($NoEmptyArray_language_id);
```

Comment: sounds confusing. Maybe tell us what your end goal is.

Comment: I just want to add the values from my $language_id into $NoEmptyArray_language_id

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for a `JOIN` so you don't do an "N+1" load, slamming a query out each time through some loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `$NoEmptyArray_language_id = array();`

Also change code with `$NoEmptyArray_language_id[] = $language_id;`

Now you have array with values in $NoEmptyArray_language_id.

If you want to get string convert this array to string using implode function.